# The relation between the length of $f(\partial D(0,1))$ and $|f'(0)|$ for a holomorphic function $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on $D(0,1+\delta)\subset \mathbb{C}$ for a fixed $\delta >0.$ Let $\gamma$ be the set $f(\partial D(0,1))$ and $L$ be the length of $\gamma.$ If $f$ is univalent, then one can see that $L\geq 2\pi|f'(0)|$ from the following computation:
\begin{equation}
2\pi|f'(0)|=\Big|\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{f'(z)}{z}dz\Big|\leq\int_{\partial D(0,1)}\frac{|f'(z)|}{|z|}|dz|=L.
\end{equation}
My question is, if $f$ is no longer univalent, is the inequality above still right? Notice that the same method does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is true and I will give a sketch of the proof.

The fundamental result we use is as follows: assume $f$ is analytic (nonconstant) on the unit disc and say $f(0)=0$, while $f(\mathbb D) \subset G$ where $G$ is a simply connected domain. If $g: \mathbb D \to G$ the unique Riemann map with $g(0)=0, g'(0)>0$, then $|f'(0)| \le g'(0)$.

This is a simple consequence of Schwarz Lemma applied to $g^{-1} \circ f: \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ as that implies $|(g^{-1} \circ f)'(0)| \le 1$, while clearly $|(g^{-1} \circ f)'(0)|=|f'(0)|/g'(0)$

Coming back to the problem here, we can assume wlog (by a translation that doesn't change anything) that $f(0)=0$; then $U=f(\mathbb D)$ domain and $\partial U \subset \gamma$; now since $\gamma$ is a holomorphic curve, its geometric self-intersections are finite (of course it can happen that $\gamma$ as a parametric curve has arcs that are repeated a few times when one moves on the unit circle) so $U$ will be bounded by at least one and possibly a few (smooth) Jordan curves that are geometrically subsets of the image of $\gamma$ and in particular there will be $J$ the outer one; so if $G$ is the inner domain of $J$, $G$ is simply connected and $U \subset G$; but the length of $\gamma$ (as a set) is then clearly at least the length of $J$ and choosing $g$ the Riemann map as above from the unit disc to $G$, one has $L \ge L(J) \ge 2\pi g'(0) \ge 2\pi |f'(0)|$ so we are done!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to be of help

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Conrad proved, the following result may be of interest:

> $2\pi |f'(0)|=L$ iff $f(z)$ is linear

To see this, one can work as follows: first suppose wlog that $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$.
Now if $L=2\pi$, take $\Omega$ to be the domain bounded by the outer Jordan  curve contained in $f(\partial \mathbb{D})$. We now claim that $f$ is injective via a standard argument with the Riemann map $g:\mathbb{D}\to \Omega$. We will actually prove that $f=g$: to see this first notice that $(g^{-1}\circ f)'(0)\le 1$ thanks to Schwarz-Pick and that $g'(0)\le L/2\pi=1$ by what whas proved in the o.p. Thus $g'(0)=f'(0)=1$, which means that $f=g$.

Since $f$ is injective we know that $$\text{Area}(f(\mathbb{D}))=\pi \sum n |a_n|^2\ge \pi |f'(0)|^2=\pi$$
By the isoperimetric inequality, $\text{Area}(f(\mathbb{D}))\le \pi$ and so $a_n$ must be $0$ for all $n\ge 2$, proving the claim.